# How can I change the email that is inside the default email texts of wordpress?

Tags: filters, login, email, password, text

Wordpress sends some various default email texts to the users.

For example when the password reset email has been sent, then the user gets an automatic email like this:

> *Hello user, This notification confirms the change of access password to NAMEOFWEBSITE. If you have not changed your password, please contact the Site Administrator at **default-admin@email.com** This message was sent to users-email@email.com Sincerely, All of us at NAMEOFWEBSITE https://www.nameofwebsite.com*

I need to keep the default admin email that i set up in wordpress. But i need to filter all emails to have another email inside the text, like this :

> *Hello user, This notification confirms the change of access password to NAMEOFWEBSITE. If you have not changed your password, please contact the Site Administrator at **another-email@email.com** This message was sent to users-email@email.com Sincerely, All of us at NAMEOFWEBSITE https://www.nameofwebsite.com*

Any ideas if this is possible with some filter?

Comment: Hi I have the same problem.
Are there any other filters where admin_mail appears?
I would like to change it for all email send to users

Comment: @Meg This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/244802)

Comment: I've converted Megs answer into a comment, @Meg don't do it again, post comments or gain enough reputation to post them, don't post replies as solutions

Answer (score 4):

There is definitely a filter for that!

Here is the reference link to wordpress developers page: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/password_change_email/

Basically adding this function (with changes) to your functions.php will override your default password reset email.

```
apply_filters( 'password_change_email', array $pass_change_email, array $user, array $userdata )
```

full example:

```
add_filter( 'password_change_email', 'rt_change_password_mail_message', 10, 3 );

function rt_change_password_mail_message( $pass_change_mail, $user, $userdata ) {

 $new_message_txt = __( 'Hi [first_name] [last_name], 

 This notice confirms that your email was changed on on our site.

 If you did not change your email, please contact the Site Administrator on our site.

 This email has been sent to [user_email]

 Regards,
ME' );
 $pass_change_mail[ 'message' ] = $new_message_txt;
 return $pass_change_mail;

}
```

Checking the notes there, you'll see that the message is part of the `$pass_change_email` array.  SO if you just want to add something to it try this...

```
add_filter( 'password_change_email', 'rt_change_password_mail_message', 10, 3 );

function rt_change_password_mail_message( $pass_change_mail, $user, $userdata ) {

 $new_message_txt = __( 'new text with phone number' );
 $pass_change_mail[ 'message' ] = $pass_change_mail[ 'message' ] . $new_message_txt;
 return $pass_change_mail;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @rudtek . I understand your idea but as i don't really want to create a new email text for every different default wordpress email (another example https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/email_change_email/ ), i just want to filter the parameter value ###ADMIN_EMAIL### that is set in all emails and change it with another one.

Any ideas on that :) ?

Comment: @Honoluluman You can simply change Administration Email in "Settings > General > Administration Email Address"

Comment: @Ankit thanks for the reply, but i need to keep the original admin email in "Settings > General > Administration Email Address" since i need to get all word press emails in that email. Just was looking for a hook to change the ###ADMIN_EMAIL### for users that receives some default emails and they can view the admin email. They should correspond in another email that i want to set up there.

Comment: @Honoluluman Please check my answer below, that may help you.

Comment: @Honoluluman try the 2nd option

Comment: @rudtek thank you very much for you time but i am not trying to add extra text to the default email.

Comment: @Ankit thank you also, but the code didn't work 

So the message says ->

Hi user, This notice confirms that your password was changed on WEBSITE. If you did not change your password, please contact the Site Administrator at ADMIN@mail.com This email has been sent to USER-EMAIL@mail.com Regards, All at WEBSITE https://www.WEBSITE.com

I just need to find a hook for ADMIN@mail.com and replace with another. The rest could stay as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you want Administrator email to remain to some email, but you need to change the admin email in password and email change email.

So you can do following.

1. Hook into `email_change_email` and `password_change_email` filters.
2. You will get the parameter `$email_change_email` and `$pass_change_email` for those filters respectively inside callback function.
3. Email text is present in `$pass_change_email['message']`, so you just have to look for the admin email in there and replace it with your new email address.
4. Return the parameter from callback function.

This can be the example for password change email.

```
/**
 * Change admin email in password change email.
 */
function change_password_change_admin_email( array $pass_change_email ) {
    $admin_email = get_option('admin_email');
    $pass_change_email['message'] = str_replace( $admin_email, 'another-email@domain.com', $pass_change_email['message'] );

    return $pass_change_email;

}
add_filter( 'password_change_email', 'change_password_change_admin_email' );
```